# Ionic Firestore Chat-unable to constantly check for updates

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am newbie at Ionic and I am trying to implement a chat service for an app I am working on. I wanted to try and use firestore and this is what I have so far.

I have managed to read and receive messages from firestore but only after I send my message.

In other words, the function to retrieve the messages only activates after I have clicked the send button.

I was wondering if there was a way for me to constantly check firestore for updates, so that the chat can be updated in "real time".

This is the code that I have for receiving the chat messages. I have placed them in the ionviewwilload() to receive all messages when entering the chatroom and when I click send on my messages.

```
retrieveCollection() : void
  {
     this._DB.getChatMessages(this._COLL,this._COLL2)
     .then((data) =>
     {
        console.log(data);
        // IF we don't have any documents then the collection doesn't exist
        // so we create it!
        if(data.length === 0)
        {
          //  this.generateCollectionAndDocument();
        }

        // Otherwise the collection does exist and we assign the returned
        // documents to the public property of locations so this can be
        // iterated through in the component template
        else
        {
           this.chats = data;
        }
     })
     .catch();
  }
```

The getchatmessages function is then linked to my provider to then retrieve my messages from firestore before returning it as a promise.

```
 getChatMessages(collectionObj: string, collectionObj2) : Promise<any>{    
    let user                : string        = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        this._DB.collection(collectionObj).doc(collectionObj2).collection("messages")
          .orderBy("sendDate", "asc")  
          .onSnapshot
          ((querySnapshot) => {
            let obj : any = [];
            querySnapshot 
            .forEach(function(doc) { 
              console.log(typeof doc);
              console.log(doc);
              obj.push({
                id : doc.id,
                message : doc.data().message,
                type : doc.data().type,
                user :doc.data().user,
                image: doc.data().image
              });
            });

            resolve(obj);
          })

        });
      }
```

So my question is to ask if there is a special method or function that I have missed in the documentation that allows me to constantly check for updates like that in a chat app.

Many thanks to those who reply.